# instantiate JPA controller by injecting from glassfish

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

How do I actually instantiate the JPA controller below?

I'm fuzzy on how a Netbeans created JPA controller is actually used.  I certainly appreciate the Netbeans wizard in this case, it's interesting -- I'm trying to understand how it works and why it works this way.

The ejb module can just inject from Glassfish along these lines:

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="JSFPU") //inject from your application server
EntityManagerFactory emf;
@Resource //inject from your application server
UserTransaction utx;
```

and then, to instantiate the controller, something like this:

```
    PersonEntityJpaController pejc = new PersonEntityJpaController(utx, emf); //create an instance of your jpa controller and pass in the injected emf and utx
    try {
        pejc.create(pe); //persist the entity
```

Where can I find more information about how to inject the PU from, in this case, Glassfish, as well as how `@Resource` works?  I don't at all mind reading Glassfish for JavaEE docs from Oracle, or other reference material.

The controller Netbeans generated:

```
package db;

import db.exceptions.NonexistentEntityException;
import db.exceptions.RollbackFailureException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

public class ClientsJpaController implements Serializable {

    public ClientsJpaController(UserTransaction utx, EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.utx = utx;
        this.emf = emf;
    }
    private UserTransaction utx = null;
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void create(Clients clients) throws RollbackFailureException, Exception {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            utx.begin();
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.persist(clients);
            utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
                utx.rollback();
            } catch (Exception re) {
                throw new RollbackFailureException("An error occurred attempting to roll back the transaction.", re);
            }
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void edit(Clients clients) throws NonexistentEntityException, RollbackFailureException, Exception {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            utx.begin();
            em = getEntityManager();
            clients = em.merge(clients);
            utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
                utx.rollback();
            } catch (Exception re) {
                throw new RollbackFailureException("An error occurred attempting to roll back the transaction.", re);
            }
            String msg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
            if (msg == null || msg.length() == 0) {
                Integer id = clients.getId();
                if (findClients(id) == null) {
                    throw new NonexistentEntityException("The clients with id " + id + " no longer exists.");
                }
            }
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void destroy(Integer id) throws NonexistentEntityException, RollbackFailureException, Exception {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            utx.begin();
            em = getEntityManager();
            Clients clients;
            try {
                clients = em.getReference(Clients.class, id);
                clients.getId();
            } catch (EntityNotFoundException enfe) {
                throw new NonexistentEntityException("The clients with id " + id + " no longer exists.", enfe);
            }
            em.remove(clients);
            utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
                utx.rollback();
            } catch (Exception re) {
                throw new RollbackFailureException("An error occurred attempting to roll back the transaction.", re);
            }
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Clients> findClientsEntities() {
        return findClientsEntities(true, -1, -1);
    }

    public List<Clients> findClientsEntities(int maxResults, int firstResult) {
        return findClientsEntities(false, maxResults, firstResult);
    }

    private List<Clients> findClientsEntities(boolean all, int maxResults, int firstResult) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            cq.select(cq.from(Clients.class));
            Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
            if (!all) {
                q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
                q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
            }
            return q.getResultList();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public Clients findClients(Integer id) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            return em.find(Clients.class, id);
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public int getClientsCount() {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            Root<Clients> rt = cq.from(Clients.class);
            cq.select(em.getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
            Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
            return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

}
```

the class which will create and call methods on the controller; it is intended to provide a single queue for the web module to pop elements (in this, `int`'s) from:

```
package db;

import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class MySingletonQueue implements RemoteQueue {

    private int next = 3;   //dummy
    private ClientsJpaController cjc;  //instantiate how?

    @Override
    public int getNext() {
        return next;  //get next int from perhaps another class or method...
    }

}
```

for context, the bean which the web page instantiates with EL:

```
package dur;

import db.RemoteQueue;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MySessionBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private RemoteQueue mySingletonQueue;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MySessionBean.class.getName());

    public MySessionBean() {
    }

    public int getNext() {
        log.info("getting next int from remote EJB");
        return mySingletonQueue.getNext();
    }

}
```

http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=47442&highlight=jpa+controller+constructor

Comment: With the amount of badges you have you should know by now this question is very much off-topic. Basically you're proving here that using IDEs to generate code is detrimental to the learning experience. Simply don't do that - write all the code yourself. That will force you to go look for proper resources to learn not only the API but also the design philosophy. 'A book' is the best place to look; apparently you want one on JEE and Glassfish.

Comment: Agree with @Gimby. You shouldn't write such crappy code. In this way, you're not going to learn anything good.

Comment: ok...beyond "crappy" can you be more specific? in a general sort of way :)

Comment: Ok :) Here it its
- JPA fits as DAO layer, which is sth separete from controller, thus naming something `ClientsJpaController` is very confusing.
Also manually beginning/ commiting transactions is very verbose and error prone - better stick with CMT (_Container Managed Transactions_). (you may take a look [this post](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/don_t_use_jpa_s)).

Comment: @GrzesiekD.  what would be a better name?  ClientsDAO?

Comment: Yes, `ClientDAO` fits much better. But also managing transactions on your own in the container environment isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is simple:

```
package db;

import javax.ejb.Singleton;


import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class MySingletonQueue implements RemoteQueue {

    private int next = 3;
    private ClientsJpaController cjc;

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction utx; 

    @PostConstruct
    public void initBean() {
        // Instantiate your controller here
        cjc = new ClientsJpaController(utx, emf);
    }

    // rest of the class ...

}
```

But keep in mind that although it will work, what you are doing is extremely messy and unmaintainable and is considered a **bad practice**.

### Update

Some advice:

1. You should inject an entity manager to your `ClientsJpaController` (also consider renaming it to `ClientDAO`)
2. Do not manage transactions in a server environment, lets server do that. Your code would be simplified to just a few lines.
3. Your entity `Clients` is in plural form, it should be singular because it represents single client, doesn't it?
4. You definitely should not do something like: `catch (Exception ex) {`, because it is a root of all exceptions. Catch only the most specific exception instead.

So, for example, your edit function can be shortened to:

```
  public Client edit(Client client) {
    return em.merge(client);
  }
```

You should definitely take a look at some EJB/ JPA book or read some decent guide.

Comment: thanks, I though it was something like, but wasn't sure.  I've mainly been looking at Oracle docs, javaee7, and a few glassfish manuals.  The EJB books I've looked at, so far, don't seem to address the specific small area which interests me:  the intersection of facelets, EJB and glassfish -- but I'll take another look for a book.

Comment: Glad it helped.  AFAIK: there is no free book for EJB 3.1, but many useful topics are clearly explained in old, free online book `Mastering Enterprise JavaBeans 3.0`. I know it has 720 pages..., but you can take a look only at chapters that interests you most.

Comment: I'll take a look at that, it seems increasingly hard to find technical books, by which I mean physical books.  I would be interested in why this approach is difficult to maintain or a bad practice, of course.